# Is it possible to achieve 0% to 100% PWM duty cycle with AT90PWM3B?

Tags: avr, pwm

I want to implement fast PWM generator using AT90PWM3B.

The chip itself has three 'Power Stage Controllers' (pwm generators). Each PSC controls two outputs (A and B). For each output there is a SET comparator value and RESET comparator value. On counter value with SET the pin goes high, on match with RESET goes low.

Since I want to use only three channels, I am going to use Channel A of each PSC, and use channel B to set frequency (counter resets on match with RESET B).

Because of that, I selected the 'one ramp' operation mode, which is defined as:
[image: AT90PWM3B One Ramp Mode]

I am going to set:

OCRnRB (RESET B) to value defining frequency. The PSC frequency (counter frequency) is 64MHz, I need output at 100kHz, so I'm going to set it to 640.

OCRnSB (SET B) to same value as RESET B, I'm not going to use this value

OCRnSA (SET A) to 0

OCRnRA (RESET B) to 'Duty Cycle (0.0 - 1.0) * 640'

Now I want to know what is going to happen on border values:

- When SET A == RESET A - Is the On-Time going to be 1-cycle or 0-cycle?
- When SET A == 0 and RESET A == 640 - Is the On-Time going to be 100% or 100% - 1 cycle?
- How can I get zero 'Dead-Time 0'? According to image from datasheet it cannot be less than single pwm period.
- Is there any way to get full range from 0% to 100% (inclusive)? I don't want to completly disable PSC, because I still want to use turn-off-on-compare feature. However, if possible, I can disable PSC at 0% if it's possible to keep it at 100%.

Comment: There are many variations and modes for the Atmel counters and I have not used AT90PWM. But I have this note in one of my files: for fast PWM mode, range is 1 pulse width to 100%; for phase correct PWM mode, range is 0 to 100%; using the OCR registers.

Comment: This is not standard timer/counter as in atmega mcus. This is special 'Power Stage Controller' which operates *AS* extended PWM generator. But there is no 'Fast PWM' or 'Phase correct' mode